# jQuery: como verificar se um elemento está oculto?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como verificar se um elemento está visível ou oculto em jQuery?

Por exemplo, um elemento pode ser oculto utilizando `.hide()`, visível utilizando `.show()` ou alternar entre oculto/visível com `.toggle()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize os seletores `:visible:` e `:hidden`. [1]

```
var isVisible = $( "#myDiv" ).is( ":visible" );
var isHidden = $( "#myDiv" ).is( ":hidden" );
```

Além disso, é possível utilizá-los direto no seletor:

```
$( "#myDiv:visible" ).animate({
    left: "+=200px"
}, "slow" );
```

[1] http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-determine-the-state-of-a-toggled-element/

*[Resposta inspirada na resposta do Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4685330/revisions)*